# Start activity from the begin

Tags: android, android-intent

I have activity A where authentication is done. After this user redirected to other activities say B,C,D. Suppose now the user is at Activity C and suddenly closes the application, next time when he launches the application it is displaying Activity C (the last activity run by user before exiting App) but,But i want to start Activity A (Authentication Purpose) when user relaunches application irrespective of where he closes the application.

Help Needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove an Activity from Stack by adding `android:noHistory="true"` attribute   in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity android:name="CurrentActivity" 
              android:launchMode="singleInstance" 
              android:noHistory="true" />
```

or by code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity_A.this,CurrentActivity_C.class); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:noHistory="true"` attribute to your `activity` tag in the manifest file. It makes sure that your `Activity` doesn't stay in the stack when it goes to background. [Here's](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) a full description. Hope this helps.